# Unable to load swrast for Anaconda spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder, fedora

I'm running Anaconda Spyder on Fedora 34.

When I run spyder I get the following error

```
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect. 
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/ted/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/ted/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libpng warning: bKGD: invalid
libpng warning: bKGD: invalid
```

I can see that libstdc++.so.6 is in /usr/lib64, but the search path is /usr/lib64/dri

How can I get iris and swrast to search /usr/lib64 for the driver?
Creating a symlink didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in this video at 14:50 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqqZ3tqgJnA

You have simply to rename files

- libstdc++.so
- libstdc++.so.6
- libstdc++.so.6.0.28

(or any that have libstdc++.so in it)

in home/anaconda3/lib

Answer (score 0):

You might try this out.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655495/trying-to-run-pygame-on-my-conda-environment-on-my-fresh-manjaro-install-and-ge

I recommend to directly copy your `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` into `(anaconda)/lib/`.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct . Also remember if you are in different environment than the base environment. Then you will have to rename
it in  that envrionment.
You will find those in env/(env_name)/lib

- libstdc++.so    -> libstdc++.so.old
- libstdc++.so.6  -> libstdc++.so.6.old
- libstdc++.so.6.0.28 -> libstdc++.so.0.28.old

Sometimes instead of libstdc++.so.6.0.28 it might be libstdc++.so.6.0.29 or any other number.

Refer this video
https://youtu.be/OqqZ3tqgJnA?t=876